# Arduino serial ports gives bad data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, arduino, node-serialport

I'm trying to receive data from my Arduino in a web(Socket.IO). So  i'll explain the code below.

Arduino:

```
 int temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;  
 Serial.print(temperatureC - 2);  
 Serial.print(" ");
```

This converts the Volt to a temperature. When i open the serial-display I can see the output how I wanted it.

```
228 
28 
28 
28 
28 
29 
28
```

But i created a SerialPort in Node and the output of that is kinda strange. I receive data on this way:

```
serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);
    socket.emit('temps', { temp: data });
   });
  });
});
```

But the output is:

```
data received: 28
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":50}]}
data received:  
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":32}]}
data received: 2
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":50}]}
data received: 8 
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":56}]}
data received: 28 
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":50}]}
data received: 28
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"temps","args":[{"temp":50}]}
data received:
```

As you can see the output is something like:

```
28
2
8
2
8
28
```

Looks like its breaking my int/strings all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your baud rate is set, 9600 is safest. 
   var sp = new SerialPort(comPort, {
        parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r"),
        baudrate: 9600,
    });

```
sp.on('data', function (arduinoData) {
    // data example
    var ArduinoString = arduinoData.toString();
}
```

I don't use the io.socket routines, you can look at my git for a working example with [Arduino and node code](https://github.com/alexmac131/NodeXbeeTank)
.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help it didn't fixed my problem but you got me in the right direction so I will just accept your answer. My result: http://github.com/Nathansakoetoe/Arduino-Temperature/blob/master/arduino.js

Comment: Nice, glad I could help, there are so many ways to do things often another view point helps.